# MySQL InnoDB lost tables but files exist

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a MySQL InnoDB which has all the database table files, but MySQL doesn't see them, and isn't loading them.

The problem happened because I deleted these three files: `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`

because I was having issues with mysql starting up, and what I read was to remove them because MySQL will just regenerate them (I know I should have backed them up but didn't).

What can I do to get MySQL to see the tables again?

```
about_member.frm                              site_stories.frm
about_member.ibd                              site_stories.ibd
db.opt                                        stories.frm
FTS_00000000000000bb_BEING_DELETED_CACHE.ibd  stories.ibd
FTS_00000000000000bb_BEING_DELETED.ibd        story_comments.frm
FTS_00000000000000bb_CONFIG.ibd               story_comments.ibd
FTS_00000000000000bb_DELETED_CACHE.ibd        story_likes.frm
FTS_00000000000000bb_DELETED.ibd              story_likes.ibd
FTS_00000000000000f5_BEING_DELETED_CACHE.ibd  story_tags.frm
FTS_00000000000000f5_BEING_DELETED.ibd        story_tags.ibd
FTS_00000000000000f5_CONFIG.ibd               story_views.frm
FTS_00000000000000f5_DELETED_CACHE.ibd        story_views.ibd
FTS_00000000000000f5_DELETED.ibd              story_view_totals.frm
member_favorites.frm                          story_view_totals.ibd
member_favorites.ibd                          tags.frm
members.frm                                   tags.ibd
members.ibd
```

Comment: Have you tried to restore those files?  The log files can stay deleted.  You really shouldn't have deleted ibdata1

Comment: I have copied the file from from an old mysql version where the file was located but the tables don't show up.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is why MySQL cannot see those files: The system tablespace (ibdata1) has a Storage-Engine specific data dictionary that lets InnoDB map out potential table usage:

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Moving InnoDB tables from one place to another requires commands like

```
ALTER TABLE tblname DISCARD TABLESPACE;
ALTER TABLE tblname IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

Here is a part of the [MySQL 5.5 Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html) explaining what needs to be considered

> Portability Considerations for .ibd Files
>
> You cannot freely move .ibd files between database directories as you
>   can with MyISAM table files. The table definition stored in the InnoDB
>   shared tablespace includes the database name. The transaction IDs and
>   log sequence numbers stored in the tablespace files also differ
>   between databases.
>
> To move an .ibd file and the associated table from one database to
>   another, use a RENAME TABLE statement:
>
> RENAME TABLE db1.tbl_name TO db2.tbl_name; If you have a “clean”
>   backup of an .ibd file, you can restore it to the MySQL installation
>   from which it originated as follows:
>
> The table must not have been dropped or truncated since you copied the
>   .ibd file, because doing so changes the table ID stored inside the
>   tablespace.
>
> Issue this ALTER TABLE statement to delete the current .ibd file:
>
> ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISCARD TABLESPACE; Copy the backup .ibd file to
>   the proper database directory.
>
> Issue this ALTER TABLE statement to tell InnoDB to use the new .ibd
>   file for the table:
>
> ALTER TABLE tbl_name IMPORT TABLESPACE; In this context, a “clean”
>   .ibd file backup is one for which the following requirements are
>   satisfied:
>
> There are no uncommitted modifications by transactions in the .ibd
>   file.
>
> There are no unmerged insert buffer entries in the .ibd file.
>
> Purge has removed all delete-marked index records from the .ibd file.
>
> mysqld has flushed all modified pages of the .ibd file from the buffer
>   pool to the file.

Given these caveats and protocols, here is a suggested course of action

For this example, let's try to restore the `tags` table to the `mydb` database

## STEP #1

Make sure you have backups of those `.frm` and `.ibd` files in `/tmp/innodb_data`

## STEP #2

Get the `CREATE TABLE tags` statement and execute it as `CREATE TABLE mydb.tags ...`. Make sure it is the exact same structure as the original `tags.frm`

## STEP #3

Delete the empty `tags.ibd` using MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.tags DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

## STEP #4

Bring in the backup copy of `tags.ibd`

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/mydb
cp /tmp/innodb_data.tags.ibd .
chown mysql:mysql tags.ibd
```

## STEP #5

Add `tags` table to the InnoDB Data Dictionary

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.tags IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

## STEP 6

Test the table's accessibility

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.tags\G
SELECT * FROM mydb.tags LIMIT 10;
```

If you get normal results, congratulations you import an InnoDB table.

## STEP 7

In the future, please don't delete ibdata1 and its logs

## Give it a Try !!!

I have discussed things like this before

- `Apr 23, 2012` : [MySQL: how to restore table stored in a .frm and a .ibd file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16911/877)
- `Sep 28, 2011` : [How to Recover an InnoDB table whose files were moved around](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6269/877)

## CAVEAT

What if you do not know the table structure of the `tags` ?

There are tools to get the CREATE TABLE statement just using the `.frm` file. I wrote a post about this as well : [How can extract the table schema from just the .frm file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44316/877). In that post, I copied a .frm file to a Windows machine from a Linux box, ran the Windows tool and got the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome Answer! I am still in the process of getting one table imported, because I keep creating problems, but I will get there eventually, and I will let you know how it works out! Thanks!

Comment: When I run the create I get: **ERROR 1813 (HY000): Tablespace for table '`weblyize`.`tags`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.** So then I try to run the alter tablespace first, and get this error: **ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'weblyize.tags' doesn't exist**. What can I do?

Comment: Thanks! To fix my error I created a new database, ran `CREATE TABLE ...` then followed your steps! You saved me from having to rewrite them 100% from scratch! It didn't import foreign keys but that is okay I can do that myself! Again Thanks!

Comment: What if I have 100 tables which should be fixed this way. I won't do operations for each table by hands. How it could be automated ?

Answer (score 10):

I have same situation, Can not drop or create specific tblname.
My fix procedure is:

1. Stop MySQL.

   ```
   service mysql stop
   ```
2. Remove ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1.

   ```
   cd /var/lib/mysql;
   rm ib_logfile0 ib_logfile1
   ```
3. Remove tblname files. **WARNING: THIS WILL PERMANTENTLY DELETE YOUR DATA**

   ```
   cd /var/lib/mysql/dbname;
   rm tblname*
   ```
4. Start MySQL.

   ```
   service mysql start
   ```

Comment: Thank got this fixed my problem, I didn't do step 3, I simply removed the logfiles and started mysql back up.

Comment: You are absolutely fantastic! Solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. I deleted `ibdata1` accidentally and all my data was lost.

After 1-2 day search in the google and SO, finally I found a solution that it saved my life (I had so many databases and tables with huge records).

1. take a backup from `/var/lib/mysql`
2. recover table schema from `.frm` file with [dbsake](https://github.com/abg/dbsake/) (there was another option! *mysqlfrm*. but it didn't work for me)

```
dbsake frmdump --type-codes /var/lib/mysql/database-name/tbl.frm
```

3. create new table (with new name) with exported schema.
4. discard new table data with this command:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl-new` DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

5. copy old table's data and paste it instead of new one and set right permission for it.

```
cp tbl.ibd tbl@002dnew.ibd && chown mysql:mysql tbl@002dnew.ibd
```

6. import data to new table.

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl-new` IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

7. alright! we have data in new table and we can drop old one.

```
DROP TABLE `tbl`;
```

7. check `/var/lib/mysql/database-name` and if there is data (`.ibd` file) for old table, delete it.

```
rm tbl.ibd
```

8. and finally rename new table to original name

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl-new` RENAME `tbl`;
```