# MariaDB Server cannot start: "InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found."

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, mariadb, innodb

After my VM server has fully crashed,
and I do not know why,
MariaDB on this Debian cannot be launched again.
Content of `error.log` with log files:

```
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: A downgrade from MariaDB 10.2.2 or later is not supported.
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-creating-innodb.html
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2019-04-15  0:40:43 139787712552320 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I doubt the `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` are corrupted
because I found [another thread](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,83939,84471#msg-84471)
where someone wanted to transfer their databases from one server to another
and the solution was properly shutdown MySQL on the server
before transfering the files.

If I remove the log files following other threads
which claim that MySQL / InnoDB can restore them,
the server crashes too but InnoDB complains that I may have missed to copy the log files. See log [here](https://gist.github.com/Zocker1999NET/380a93436491b60279b96c6a31fb1310) (log posted on GitHub, too long for StackExchange)

If I also remove `ibdata1`, the server starts
but I cannot access the databases
because "The table 'xyz' doesn't exist in engine".
[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/675445/mysql-innodb-lost-tables-but-files-exist) mentions that I may can restore my data
but I cannot simply follow the solution as I have to apply it to over 200 tables.

I am using `mysqld  Ver 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (Debian 9.6)`
and I have used the default configuration of MariaDB for Debian except following:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_large_prefix=ON
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=ON
```

Is there a way to restore or repair the database data?

PS: Now the server will get a cron job using `mysqldump` every hour to prevent the issue that the newest dump is over 2 months old ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to restore my data with MySQL itself,
the trick was to force InnoDB to recover the databases / tables.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html.
I needed to use `innodb_force_recovery = 6` for MySQL to accept my corrupted files.

Only one table seems to be non-restorable,
seems that this table caused the inconsistency.